# Ayuda con repeater anidado

Tags: c#, asp.net

espero que me puedan ayudar, tengo esta encuesta que tiene un repeater anidado.

Quiero acceder a los datos "IDPregunta" y "Pregunta" para poder guardarlos en base de datos. Pero no puedo acceder al childrepeater.

Estoy intentando acceder asi:

```
Repeater rptdos = (Repeater)rptuno.Items[0].FindControl("rptdos"); 
int value =Convert.ToInt32(((Label)rptdos.Items[0].FindControl("lblkeypregunta")).Text);
            acceso_datos.IDPregunta1 = Convert.ToInt32(value);`
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
introducir el códig<asp:Repeater ID="rptuno" runat="server">
             <itemtemplate>
            <b>




          <td> <asp:Label ID="lblkeycategoria" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "IDCategoria") %>' Runat="server"/>
                    <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "NombreCategoria") %>

                </b>
                <br> 

                    <asp:Repeater ID="rptdos" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rptDos_ItemDataBound" 
                    datasource='<%# ((DataRowView)Container.DataItem).Row.GetChildRows("myrelation") %>' >
                    <itemtemplate>

       <td> <asp:Label ID="lblkeypregunta" Text=' <%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "[\"IDPregunta\"]")%>' runat="server"></asp:Label>

                             <br><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "[\"Pregunta\"]")%><br>

             <td>  <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbcontrol" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
                <asp:ListItem Text="Nunca" Value="0"> </asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="Algunas veces" Value="1"> </asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="Frecuentemente" Value="2"> </asp:ListItem>
                <asp:ListItem Text="Siempre" Value="3"> </asp:ListItem>


            </asp:RadioButtonList>    </td>

</itemtemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
</itemtemplate>
```

o aquí

Comment: winforms? wpf? o que metodologia de diseño usas? recibis alguna clase de error? como es el diseño del formulario?

Comment: es aspx.net con c#

Comment: Aclaralo en las etiquetas, y despues mostra el aspx que genera esto.

Comment: listo he agregado el código del repeater